# 2004 Honda Odyssey won't start for a few seconds after key moved to ON position

Tags: honda, starting, odyssey

I have a 2004 Honda Odyssey. Yesterday, it starting having an issue where it would no longer start. The engine would not even crank, but there did not appear to be a battery or battery connection issue as lights, radio, et al still worked and did not seem to dim or be affected when key turned to crank/start position.

After some trial and error, checking battery cables, etc, I noticed that when the key was moved to the ON position, the D light on the transmission dash indicator remained lit for a few seconds and I could hear what sounded like a motor running or buzzing of some sort for about 2 seconds. Once that stops and the light goes off, then I can turn the key to the start/crank position and the engine will start fine.

It didn't do this until yesterday. What might be failing or going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was the starter motor that had died. We had it replaced and everything's good again. The D light was apparently a mistaken symptom. They said there were no issues with the transmission.

Answer (score 2):

The buzzing you are hearing is the fuel pump priming/pressurizing the fuel system, this is a normal sound. Most people don't hear it because the engine is normally in the process of starting at that time.

The D light suggests the PCM has detected an issue related to the transmission and may have a trouble code stored. Get the code read.

Comment: Have a dealer appt on Friday. We'll see what the outcome is.